# Default option of select is not showing

Tags: html, css, angular

I have one select that i need to put a default select option, but it's not showing in my template.

I tried:

```
<div class="select">

    <select (change)="calculaMes(mesEscolhido)" [(ngModel)]="mesEscolhido" name="selectMesEscolhido"
    class="select-text">
       <option class="dropdown-item" disabled selected value>Teste</option>
       <option [hidden]="datasComMovimentacoes[x].data == mesEscolhido" *ngFor="let mes of datasComMovimentacoes;let x = index"
       class="dropdown-item">{{mes.data}}</option>
    </select>

   <span class="select-highlight"></span>
   <span class="select-bar"></span>

</div>
```

I don't believe this is caused by my css, but, this is my css:

```
 .select {
    font-family:
      'Roboto','Helvetica','Arial',sans-serif;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 5%;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #757575!important;
  }

  .select-text {
      margin-top: 10%;
      position: relative;
      font-family: inherit;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #757575!important;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-radius: 0;
      border: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.12);
  }

  /* Remove focus */
  .select-text:focus {
      outline: none;
      color: #757575!important;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0);
  }

      /* Use custom arrow */
  .select .select-text {
      appearance: none;
      color: #757575!important;
      -webkit-appearance:none
  }
```

This is my result in template:

[image]

Comment: what is the current & expected output?

Comment: The current is the image that i posted in this question. the expected is "Teste"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default option will be selected if the `value` attribute of the option tag is set to the default value of the `selectedOption` property on your Component. Let's say you didn't initialize the `selectedOption` property, then by default it's value will be `undefined`. And so, this `value` attribute of the `option` tag should be `undefined` in that case.

```
...
<option class="dropdown-item" disabled selected value="undefined">Select an Option</option>
...
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-list-default-option-selected?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

to whom to be interested, this don't be showing because my *nyif. i changed by [hidden] and now i have the expected selected label. i don't no why

Comment: there is difference between [hidden] and *ngIf. [hidden] element will be always present on your dom just not visible whereas if you use *ngIf, the element occupies DOM only if the conditions is true!