# Default option in <select> not showing

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am experiencing a stupid issue with a `<select>`. My toolchain of choice is Vue.js with Bootstrap and I am trying to create a dynamic `<select>` that is populated with Vue. My issue however is that the default option in the `<select>` is not showing, instead the form-element is blank.

This is my coding, the input group is almost identical to the example provided in the Bootstrap documentation. I also tried the suggestions mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860383/default-option-of-select-is-not-showing) however they did not work.

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label
        class="input-group-text"
        for="action_manufacturer_input">Manufacturer</label>
  </div>
  <select
      v-model="form.manufacturer"
      class="custom-select"
      id="manufacturer_input">
    <option disabled selected value="undefined">Please select one...</option>
    <option
        v-for="manufacturer in manufacturers"
        v-bind:value="manufacturer.id">
      {{ manufacturer.display_name }} : {{ manufacturer.full_name }}
    </option>
    <option v-on:click="toggle_input()">Add new manufacturer...</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

As a sanity check I removed the Bootstrap styling however that did not change anything. My question: how do I get the default selected option to show?

P.S. For what it's worth my back-end is Laravel, however I don't see how it could cause an issue.

Comment: Interesting.  Try taking `disabled` off of it.

Comment: @Taplar nope I tried that. I also tried removing the value. No cigar

Comment: Do you have any more code? Putting it into a Vue fiddle displays it just fine for me.

Comment: @Martin I don't have any more relevant code save for the Axios I use to populate the manufacturer dataset, which code in particular would you want to see? I do not make any changes to the default bootstrap css.

Comment: Then *that* or something else is breaking your code, because simply adding what you provided into a fiddle with vue and bootstrap 4 displays everything as expected. https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/ZEQvZdG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Martin who in the comments section prompted me to look elsewhere and I found it. (@Cristian Incarnato answered the question as I answered it). I have a habit from C++ of initializing all my data  variables with `null` values. So my data variables were being set as:

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        manufacturer: null,
      }
    };
  },
```

By changing the above to the following:

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        manufacturer: "Please select one...",
      }
    };
  },
```

This fixed the issue. Thanks to all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The v-model of your select is binded with **form.manufacturer** state

What is the value of **form.manufacturer** ?

You need to cheek that, because, Vue is searching an option that match to the value of form.manufacturer.

I have created this [codepen](https://codepen.io/cincarnato/pen/KKVZYOO?editors=1010) as example

```
<div id="app">

  <!--Bind select value with form.category-->
  <select name="options" v-model="form.category">

    <!--Add an empty (no value) option-->
    <option :value="null">Choose a Category</option>

    <!--Add options when value is id-->
    <option v-for="category in categories" 
            :key="category.id"
            :value="category.id"
    >
      {{category.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

  <!--See how the state change when option select change-->
  <div>Value of Category: {{form.category}}</div>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    form:{
      category: null
    },
    categories: [
      {id: 1, name:"Category 1"},
      {id: 2, name:"Category 2"},
      {id:3, name:"Category 3"}
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: See my answer below, but yes I was initializing the value to something Vue could not find. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Gosh you were right !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my disabled option was not showing in a Select and the only thing that was missing was the binding of the value property on the disabled (desired default) option.

Not working:

```
 <option disabled value="null">Select one</option>
```

vs. Short hand Working:

```
 <option disabled :value="null">Select one</option>
```

Long form working:

```
 <option disabled v-bind:value="null">Select one</option>
```

Notice the value attribute is not bound to anything in the first example, thus Vue is unable to assign it.